# scrape data after hover over element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

From this link:
https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/usa/wta-miami/golubic-viktorija-swiatek-iga-j9oF2Lr6/,
I want to scrape data that appears after hover over this element `24%`:
[image]

the text I want to get is `4 out of 17 users predicted this`

I tried using selenium but return error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:/chromedriver.exe"), options=options)
driver.get(u)

s = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.foot.predictions .center.disabled .pred')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(s).perform()

print(driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.foot.predictions .center.disabled .pred').text)
```

return error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".foot.predictions .center.disabled .pred"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we see _`User Predictions Log in to show!`_. Do you have demo creds for testing?

Comment: usually values are hidden somewhere in HTML - ie as `data=".."` in hovered tag. So first you could check if value 24 is somewhere in HTML - maybe it will be your value and you may get it.